# How to implement a database filled ListView to another xml created ListView?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview

I created a database with data that I put into a `ListView`. Since it was created programmatically, there is no xml file that contains this `ListView`. Code:

```
public class hornot extends Application{

  public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
  public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "persons_hotness";
  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb";
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private DbHelper ourHelper;
  private final Context ourContext;
  private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

  private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  public DbHelper(Context context) {
  super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
   KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
   KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
   KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
   );

  }
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
  onCreate(db);
  }

   }
 public hornot(Context c) {
  ourContext = c;
  }

 public hornot open() throws SQLException{ //ez a throws kell az SQLiteExample.java try részhez
  ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
  ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
  }
```

This is how I put the items into the `ListView`:

```
 ListView lv;
  ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> todoItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems));

   final ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
  final hornot info = new hornot(this);
  info.open();

  Cursor c = info.getAllTitles();
  if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
        do{
                 todoItems.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2));
         }while (c.moveToNext());
       }
            if (todoItems.size() > 0)
            {
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(sqview.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems));
            }
```

I created an xml and I'd like to put the programmatically created `ListView` into another `ListView`(with the id `listplus`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/b1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
  <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/b2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/listplus" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"><;/ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How could I do that?

Comment: 1. Why is your `hornot` extending `Application`? 2. Where do you use the layout with the `ListView` with the id `listplus`(it's another activity?)

Comment: @slukian 1. hornot extending Application is a mistake, it is not there :)  2. yes, i would like to use it in another activity

Comment: I dont know if it is possible, but i would like all the methods to be working in the new listview, just like in the old one.

Comment: Your best option is to use a `hornot` object in each class, and then use it like you did above to populate the list from the second activity with the id `listplus`. Your code is somewhat strange, you have the `ListActivity` that you populate but you are trying to build the same layout(probably with some variations) in another activity. Maybe you just want the xml layout with the `ListView` `listplus` in the current activity?

Comment: I would like to create an activity where I create buttons, textveiws, some images etc, and I need my database for example under the buttons. It's very impotant for me to handle these items free (change opacity, color, etc) this is why I would like to put the whole database into an xml created activity. If you can help me to change this programmatically created listvew to an xml created listview, it is good as well. :)

Comment: Then make a `hornet` object in your new `Activity` and use it as you did until now. For example in the `onCreate` method of the new `Activity` you could call `getAllTitles()` on the `hornet` object to get a `Cursor` and populate the `ListView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you just want an `ListActivity` with a custom layout. Right now you use a `ListActivity`(that by default shows just a full screen list), if you want to have other elements besides the list(buttons, images etc) set the content view to a xml layout. If you set your content view to a custom layout, in that layout you **must** have a `ListView` with the id `"@android:id/list"` so that your `ListView` knows where to bind the data. So if you want to use the layout you posted modify it and add the required `id` to the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/b1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
  <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/b2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your current `ListActivity` that you used just add the line:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.the_name_of_above_layout); // <=this line
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems));

     final ListView lv = getListView();
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     final hornot info = new hornot(this);
     info.open();

     Cursor c = info.getAllTitles();
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            todoItems.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
     }
     if (todoItems.size() > 0) {
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (sqview.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems));
     }
```

Comment: So much time goes away with finding my mistake then you say I must have ListView with the id  "@android:id/list" :) Thank you for your help again, I am a beginner, i would've never found out that the problem is this. Just for curiosity if I had more listviews, what could be the ids of those? Since android:id/list is  only one id and android:id/list2 is not accepted.

Comment: @JaniBela `ListActivity` only has one list with that `id` (`@android:id/list`, and manages only this `ListView`) . If you want more `ListView` in the same layout besides the one with the special id then you will give them any id you want but also you will have to manage yourself because `ListActivity` will only take care of one list only.